# Python not writing to file when run from Terminal, but works from my IDE

Tags: python, csv, command-line, file-writing

I'm using Anaconda Python 3.6.1 on Windows 10.

My program takes weather data from an Atom feed and writes it to a .csv file every 30 minutes (or 2 seconds for testing purposes). When I run the program from PyCharm, it writes the data no problem. However, when I try to run the program from the command line the .csv file is completely unchanged. I added a print statement after the writing and it prints to the terminal every 2 seconds no problem, it just doesn't write the data.

I call it through command line this way:

```
python e:\documents\pythonprojects\weatherfeed\weatherfeed.py
```

and my functions that write data are as follows:

```
def write_current_temp():
""" Writes current temperature to weather_data.csv on same line """
with open('weather_data.csv', 'a') as wd:
    wd.write(get_current_temp() + ',')

def new_day():
""" Creates a new line, adds yy.mm.dd to line, adds current temp """
with open("weather_data.csv", 'a') as wd:
    wd.write("\n")
    wd.write(time.strftime("%y.%m.%d,"))
    wd.write(get_current_temp() + ',')
```

where get_current_temp() gets the current temperature from the feed and returns it as a string

weather_data.csv is in the same folder as my .py file and it works 100% perfectly when I run it from PyCharm

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Thanks!

Edit: Using Python 3.6.1 on PyCharm, I'm pretty sure that's the only version I've ever installed on this machine. The command line appears to be running 3.6.1: I don't have it installed on my path so I run from e:\applications\anaconda and checking the version that way on the command line yields this:

```
e:\Applications\Anaconda>python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying a relative location for the file, which will be relative to the directory from which you run the script, not the directory where the script lives.

You can try something like this to force it to look at the same directory as the script:

```
import os 
this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
file_path = os.path.join(this_dir, 'weather_data.csv')
with open(file_path, 'a') as wd:
    wd.write(get_current_temp() + ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I am not sure if this is your case, but please check which python version Pycharm is running and which version your terminal is running. One of them could be running the python3.5 and the other 2.7, this could cause some issues. But again, I am not sure if this is your case, please update your question with the versions of pythons that you're running.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the reply!